# CMS (Web Application OR Windows Application)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I am a little bit puzzled about something. I am creating a ASP.NET MVC eCommerce application and currently I have written all the back end in ASP.NET MVC.

I was thinking if its better to write all the management in WPF instead of HTML, as its probably even less prone to be exploited by hackers.

I am a Windows user so I am not really bothered about using Linux/Mac at the moment so I am quite aware that having all the back-end written in HTML will allow users to have access to the admin area using other OS.

I would like to see what are the advantages and disadvantages of having WPF to manage the content of the website as its probably much easier to develop and manage (think about Live Writer).

Answer (score 1):

4-5 years ago a desktop app would probably be what you wanted to use.  These days the browser is the OS and if its not on the web people just won't use it.  On the web you get simplified deployment and anybody can access it anywhere.  With WPF you get...  shinier gradients?

"I was thinking if its better to write all the management in WPF instead of HTML, as its probably even less prone to be exploited by hackers."

An intranet website would be just as secure as a internal wpf application.

Comment: There is a whole lot more to deciding whether to write a native or a web app. For instance, 'deployment' is not simplified, it is centralized. If your customer doesn't have a web server then what? If your customer doesn't have app install privileges to the web server, then what?

Also, native apps, including WPF, bring more to the table than 'shinier gradients'. Native hardware, LAN, and OS access are just a few. iPhone apps, as of this writing, are in no danger of losing ground to web apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have combine both and make it in Silverlight (and gain most advantages and disadvantages of both - you will have a rich UI, but at cost of platform independence).

I don't think it is a very good solution for eCommerce backend though, HTML + JS can offer you all the flexibility you need and with JS libraries like jQuery is writing impressive UIs quite easy.

I personally hate platform-dependent website backends (I can recall one CMS that requiread IE 6 to work, it was total pain in the *** :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

1)  Is your team primarily made of web developers?  Does it make sense for them all to learn/use WPF development?

2)  How will you deploy updates to the WPF app?  One thing I like about web-based internal tools is you don't have to worry about versioning/deployment so much.

3)  How will you authenticate users?  For an internal application that uses domain based security, I think a web app is much easier as IIS and the browser will take care of authentication/login session.